# Are the negative answers included when using a helper function that is defined in the positives?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have $f(x):=\begin{cases}\frac{\ln (x)}{x-1} \quad &,x\in(0,1)\cup(1,\infty) \\ 1 &,x=1\end{cases}$

And need to solve $(x^2+7)^{2x^2+2}<(2x^2+3)^{x^2+6}$

The function is continous; $\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\ln (x)}{x-1}=\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\ln (x)-\ln (1)}{x-1}=1=f(1)$

And differentiable by L'Hosptial at $1$

So we have and we can show $f'(x)<0$ $\forall x \in (0,1)\cup(1,\infty)$ and since it's continous at $1$ $f$ is strictly decreasing.

So \begin{equation*} (x^2+7)^{2x^2+2}<(2x^2+3)^{x^2+6} \text{ is defined }\forall x \in \mathbb{R}
\\ \Leftrightarrow  \frac{\ln (x^2+7)}{x^2 +6}<\frac{\ln (2x^2+3)}{2x^2 +2}\\ \Leftrightarrow f(x^2+7)<f(2x^2+3) \\ \Leftrightarrow  x^2+7>2x^2+3\\ \Leftrightarrow|x|<2  \end{equation*}

Because I went through $f$ my first thought was to restrict the answers to its domain so $x\in(0,2)$ but I can also tell that the negative answers work but how do I justify including them when they aren't part of its domain? The answers in the back of the book say $x\in (-2,2)$ while taking the exact same steps as I did yet I'm still not convinced for some reason.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you're not taking f(x), you're taking f(x^2+7) and f(2x^3 + 3). If there are domain limitations, you would use them there. Also, I think 2x^3 is a typo for 2x^2, meaning the argument values are always greater than 0

Comment: Fixed the typo; And I think I get it. When subbing in $f$ we say that the inside value should be positive which is true $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. Should that be the process?

Comment: The ambiguity in my mind arises because $f$ just shows up. It's not like I had $x<x+1$ and applied $f$ as stritcly increasing for example.

Comment: Not sure if this answers your comment, but, yes, you can't just apply f() like that. You need to show f is increasing, and f inverse is decreasing for those inequalities to hold. It won't work for every function f. Of course, you would also have to show f inverse exists at all since it could be multivalued (however, if f is strictly increasing, I think you can prove that). NOTE: I think you might have a sign flip since f is apparently decreasing not increasing